# Air pressure on Mars below ground

Tags: barometric-pressure, mars

As I understand, in deep mines on Earth the air pressure increases with depth. At what depth on Mars would the air pressure reach 14psi (97 kPa)?

Comment: Why the particular interest in 14 psi???

Answer (score 1):

The [Mars Atmosphere Model](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/K-12/rocket/atmosmrm.html) web page by Nasa lists the equation for atmospheric pressure as,

$P = 0.699e^{-0.00009h}$

Where pressure, $P$ is in kilopascals and $h$ is height is in meters.

Rearranging the equation,

$h= - \frac{ln(\frac{P}{0.699})}{0.00009}$

For a pressure of 97 kPa,

$h= - \frac{ln(\frac{97}{0.699})}{0.00009} \ = \ -54\ 809 \ m \ = \ -54.8 \ km$

Which means the atmosphere would need to be 54.8 km below the surface of Mars to have a pressure of 97 kPa.